# When I add a column to a JTable, table.getColumnCount() doesn't change

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I try to add a column to a `JTable` (named "table"):

```
TableColumn newCol = new TableColumn();
newCol.setHeaderValue("Grant User");
table.addColumn(newCol);
```

Before I add the new column,  the method `table.getColumnCount()` returned 5 (I have 5 columns); after that, it still returns 5. Why?

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I tried this below sample and it does work correctly as expected, explained with in line comments: `DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(1, 2);
  JTable table = new JTable(model); //Created with 2 column
  System.out.println(table.getColumnCount()); // prints 2
  table.addColumn(new TableColumn());//added column
  System.out.println(table.getColumnCount());// prints 3
  
  table = new JTable(); //created with no columns
  System.out.println(table.getColumnCount()); //prints 0
  table.addColumn(new TableColumn());//added column
  System.out.println(table.getColumnCount());//prints 1`

Comment: Post your full code, there might be some issue with that

Comment: `I tried this below sample and it does work correctly as expected,` - so you have proved that the basic code works. So now you need to debug your real code to see what is different. We can't help you do that.

Comment: today, I tried again, it works. I don't understand why. anyway, it works now. Thank you!